# Return value of select() with empty sets

Tags: c

I have a client which adds sockets fd's to FD_SET, and later in the code i want to use select() mechanism on this FD_SET i have.
If the "master" fd_set contains no items at all, what is the return value of select()? What will is my "fdmax" parameter ?  0?

I need to handle such case, where my set is actually empty.. I just wonder if its possible to handle it implicitly, without special counter + if { }

Answer (score 3):

It will work just fine.

The [manual page for Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) states:

> Some code calls select() with all three sets empty, nfds zero, and a non-NULL timeout as a fairly portable way to sleep with subsecond precision.

So, there's nothing strange with using empty sets. Sets can be empty, that's a part of their definition. And yes, you must pass 0, since you're supposed to pass one more than the largest descriptor.

I suggest defining your API to parties that need to add descriptors like so:

```
int add_fds(FD_SET *set);
```

and have them return 1 + (the largest descriptor added), or 0 if none was added as per above.

The return value will likely be 0, the manual page says:

> On success, select() and pselect() return the number of file descriptors contained in the three returned descriptor sets (that is, the total number of bits that are set in readfds, writefds, exceptfds) which may be zero if the timeout expires before anything interesting happens.

Comment: or in different words, the return value would be zero when sets are empty too. thanks

Comment: The return value can be zero (for timeout) or -1 (for error, such as interrupted system call, which you should handle)

Comment: without timeout given (using null) is it safe to say that if select returns 0, it means that all the given fd_sets to select() were empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
when u try to connect server-side, server must to accept this connect with serverfd or what ever u want to say it. Then server after the accept conneciton u, will use FD_SET(new_client_fd, &readfds). At last u will check with the FDISSET(new_client_fd, &readfds). If return true u can read the socket.

Client side after the connect(...,...,..), u can use again select. Such as

client_read_fd = connect(...,...,.. server info)
maxfd = client_read_fd +1
int a=select(maxfd, &readfds,null,null.....)

a shows u how many fds are 1 so ready to read.
```

Comment: It would be nice to avoid texting slang (such as "u" instead of you)

Comment: S.O. doesn't have a 140 character limit:)